How to Correctly Format URL Redirects to Exclude Extra Slash in Web.config?
I'm working with URL rewriting in a Web.config file and I'm facing an issue with an extra slash appearing in my redirected URLs. Here’s the rule I've got so far:
<rule name="Redirect Users to Candidates" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^users(.*)" /> <action type="Redirect" url="candidates{R:1}" /> </rule>
This rule is intended to redirect URLs in two scenarios:
When navigating to /users?text=smith, it redirects to /candidates/?text=smith. However, I want it to redirect to /candidates?text=smith without the additional slash before the query string.
It is also intended to redirect /users/A123456 to /candidates/A123456, which it does successfully, but I cannot get it to not have the additional trailing slash when there is a query string involved.
Thank you in advance!

Maybe share your entire rule config. It sounds like you have two rules at least, so maybe hey are interfering with each other.

simple test, Based on the rewrite rules you provided, I test and it works fine. Please provide the complete code for section <rewrite> in Web.config.

We fixed it with the addition of appendQueryString="true" as shown below.
<rule name="Redirect Users to Candidates" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url="^users(.*)" /> 
  <action type="Redirect" url="candidates{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" /> 
</rule>

